# Excel VBA - FormatConditions

Tags: excel, vba

i want to use the follow vba code in my application

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Mod(Column(), 2)"
```

I'm getting an error

> Error Number 5. Invalid Argument

What is wrong with that code?
THX

This is my complete code in my sub.. all FomatConditions are working fine - except the last two..

```
    ' FormatConditions
With Range("K6:BH" & lastUsedRow)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    ' Prozent
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Prozent"
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 170, 170)
    With .FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ' Prozent unter
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ProzentUnter"
    .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    With .FormatConditions(2).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ' ist
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Ist"
    .FormatConditions(3).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206)
    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.Pattern = xlLightUp
    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.PatternColor = RGB(68, 84, 106)
    With .FormatConditions(3).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ' ist unter
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IstUnter"
    .FormatConditions(4).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.Pattern = xlLightUp
    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.PatternColor = RGB(68, 84, 106)
    With .FormatConditions(4).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ' Plan
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Planen"
    .FormatConditions(5).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.Pattern = xlLightUp
    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.PatternColor = RGB(68, 84, 106)
    With .FormatConditions(5).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ' timee
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=K$5=$F$1"
    .FormatConditions(6).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions(6).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180)
    With .FormatConditions(6).Borders(xlLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = RGB(209, 136, 27)
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(6).Borders(xlRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = RGB(209, 136, 27)
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(COLUMN(), 2)"
    .FormatConditions(7).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
    '.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Mod(Column(), 2)=0"
    '.FormatConditions(8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett i edited my post - this is my complete code ;)

Comment: Tested that, no error. Please can you read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes i can. I tested the two lines of code on 2 computers. I'm still getting this errors. I hate vba.. bus thanks. My time is over and i have to send this worksheet to my prof ;)

Answer (score 6):

The reason are regional settings on your computer. Instead of `comma` you should use `semicolon` to separate formula arguments. Therefore instead of this line:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Mod(Column(), 2)"
```

use this one:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Mod(Column(); 2)"
```

Or you could change your regional settings alternatively.

Comment: Great catch! Sometimes it just takes the right experience. This isn't obvious to someone who never saw anything but commas separating formulas arguments.

Comment: Is this common in countries which use the `comma` as a decimal separator?

Comment: AFAIK yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

A very good answer has already been posted but as a complement:

Use `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`.

```
Dim sep As String: sep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(COLUMN()" & sep & "2)"
```

This should work no matter the regional settings.